# 2003 jetta 2.0 was great until the fuel pump went out

Tags: vw, jetta, dtc

Got the car for $800 needed pads and rotors all around. Only driven on weekends for a month and was great. The fuel pump went out I replaced with a rebuild and the sending line broke while putting it in without knowing. I replaced the relay and a few other things before finding out about the line. I replaced the broken line and now I have a list of 12 codes that weren't there before as well as the car being stuck in 3rd gear(automatic) and seemed to die only in park sometimes when I shut the driver door then cleared the codes and it won't start again.

- 865-ecm power relay
- 261 267 270 and 264- injector circuit low voltage
- 445- evaporative emissions
- 0036- o2 sensor
- 418- secondary air injection system
- 2401-evap leak detection pump
- 748-pressure control solenoid trans
- 141-o2 sensor b1s2

Comment: Just based off of the evap leak detections, it seems like you may or may not have used the correct size of line.

Comment: Didn't have the money to deal with a new fuel pump again. I just used fuel line to replace the 6 inch long line from pump to itself where it then is sent to the motor